# query with pagination causing high throughput usage

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I use Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB account, version 3.6. In queries using [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) I noticed higher throughput usage. The higher skip is the more costly query is.

```
db.MyCollection.find({Property:"testtest"}).skip(12000).limit(10)
```

Above query costs around 3000 RU. The property that is in find clause is my partition key.  I have read that currently cosmosdb is capable of doing queries with offset and limit but I found that officaly only in SQL API for CosmosDb there's [OFFSET LIMIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit) clause. Is it possible with MongoDb API either or should I live with costly queries with skip ?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL API will yield the same result with `OFFSET LIMIT`. You'll find an almost linear increase in RU as you increase the offset as each query loops over all skipped documents.

If possible you should try to use the continuation token if possible in your context. You could also adjust your filter criteria using a indexed property to move over your data.

> The RU charge of a query with OFFSET LIMIT will increase as the number of terms being offset increases. For queries that have multiple pages of results, we typically recommend using continuation tokens. Continuation tokens are a "bookmark" for the place where the query can later resume. If you use OFFSET LIMIT, there is no "bookmark". If you wanted to return the query's next page, you would have to start from the beginning.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-offset-limit)

Comment: I can't find if there's any way to use ContinuationToken with mongodb api

Comment: @JakubW I'm not sure if there's such a thing for the mongodb sdk as I normally don't make use of it so the only option might be using a filter criteria.